# Year Field breaking biblatex

Tags: xelatex, biblatex

I am using Visual Studio Code to compile my Latex file and when using Biblatex for my bibliography management, adding the year field breaks the build process.
This is my bib file:

```
@online{test:1,
    title = {test reference},
    url = {https://google.com},
    author = {yes},
    year = {2011},
    urldate = {2023-1-1}
}
@online{test:2,
    title = {test reference 2},
    urldate = {2023-1-1}
}
```

and my latex file:

```
%Preamble
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=apa,
sorting=ynt
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\nocite{*}

\addbibresource{Projectile.bib}

\begin{document}
random text.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Omitting the year field allows the build to finish but I need the year field for proper APA referencing. When it doesn't work, i get an output along the lines of "cannot find 'document.bcf'!"

Answer (score 0):

I just had to reinstall biber